Generating tuples with a range for average
I am trying to generate 67 distinct tuples with a certain avaerage but my method is not working (can't even find 1), is there are a way to do this that will be quicker? Here is my code:
pair_distinct(pairs: List[tuple], pair: tuple) -> bool:
    """ Check if the given pair is distinct from all pairs in the set """
    if pair[0] == pair[1]:
        return False
    pair_set = set(pair)
    for existing_pair in pairs:
        if pair_set == set(existing_pair):
            return False
    return True


def gen_avg(expected_avg=8, n=67, a=0, b=16):
    """ Generate pairs of coordinates such that the average of the pairs is +-1 the expected average """
    while True:
        pairs = []
        first_coordinate = [randint(a, b) for _ in range(n)]
        second_coordinate = [randint(a, b) for _ in range(n)]

        # Generate pairs
        for i in range(n):
            pair = (min(first_coordinate[i], second_coordinate[i]), max(first_coordinate[i], second_coordinate[i]))
            if pair_distinct(pairs, pair):
                pairs.append(pair)

        # Check if we have exactly n pairs
        if len(pairs) == n:
            print(pairs)
            # Compute the average
            total_sum = sum(x + y for x, y in pairs)
            average = total_sum / (2 * n)

            if abs(average - expected_avg) <= 1:
                return pairs ```


We're not a coding site, and coding questions are off-topic.  We discourage questions that are just a big block of code.  We expect you to state the problem statement in a self-contained way (rather than "optimize this code" or "do whatever this code does").  We're looking to build an archive of knowledge, so we hope questions will be on matters that will be useful to others in the future.

(The programming language you chose suports set) (quicker Take short-cuts. Cheat. Keep a running total for early outs. Compute (bounds for) the last pair. Be sure to check deviations from uniform random are tolerable.)

Can you explain what you actually try to achieve? I’m not going to reverse engineer your code because you say it’s not working. I would have taken the tuples (8-k, 8+k) for 1 <= k <= 67.
